# Flexbox position one div to the right of others when there is enough space to do so

Tags: css, flexbox

So imagine we have four divs. On a small screen, I want them to look like the following picture. 4 boxes stacked one on top of the other and centered nicely. Easy enough. 
[image: 4 boxes stacked one on top of the other]

Once the screen is big enough, I'd like for the 3rd div in the row to pop over to the right side, while still keeping the other 3 stacked and on the left side. How would I do this with flexbox or some other css technique?

Thanks very much. I'm sure this is a duplicate somehow but I wasn't able to find my exact scenario. 
[image: four boxes with the 3rd one to the right of the others]

Comment: please you can  post your source code?

Comment: No, this is not possible natively with flexbox.

Comment: You'll need to use media queries.

Comment: the source code is just ~4 divs of roughly 400px widths by default

Comment: @Aziz Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @majorBummer see my answer.

Comment: You can use the flex `order` property in combination with my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/36967135/3597276

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `@media` query for the breakpoint, you could reorder the the flex children and force linebreaks by using `flex-wrap: wrap`, percentage widths and `margin-right` for `child2` and `child4` to have them in the same width as `child1`

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1em;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.flex .child {
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 0.1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .flex {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex .child {
    order: 3;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .flex .child:nth-of-type(1) {
    order: 1;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .flex .child:nth-of-type(3) {
    order: 2;
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .flex .child:nth-of-type(2), .flex .child:nth-of-type(4) {
    margin-right: 66.66%;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/3snvjyp5/

---

### Edit: dynamic heights / faux-masonry layout

If you want `child3` to have a tall height without creating whitespace, you could apply `position: absolute` so that it doesn't affect the flow while all other children are under each other with `margin-right` equal to `child3`'s width:

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1em;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.flex .child {
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 0.1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .flex {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex .child {
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-right: 66.66%;
  }
  .flex .child:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 62.66%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%; right: 2%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child" style="height: 100px;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="height: 200px;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="height: 600px;">3</div>
  <div class="child" style="height: 400px;">4</div>
</div>
```

This code is more simplified since we do not need to reorder the children.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/d0pk8p89/

Comment: Does this rely on the divs having the same heights? I added heights to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3snvjyp5/5/
I'd like for div 2 and 4 to slide up and fill the space left by div3 if possible.

Comment: Yes and no. If `child3` is taller than `child1` it will create whitespace between `child1` and `child2`.. the others can have different heights (2 and 4) - see example: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/ema05hbg/ - did you want this to behave differently?

Comment: Yes. I should have made it clearer when asking the question initially. Divs 2 and 4 need to slide up next to div 1 even if child3's height > child1's height

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it in a serial order than you can use flexbox and just assign a min-width to all your components and they flex:1; so they will try to fit in till they have room and stack only if need be..

If you want the screen to be occupied if if div 3 can fit and div 2 cannot then you might want to look at Jquery masonry..it will help you fill the space with whichever content can fit in..

Comment: I'm using React with this project currently so would rather not have to mess with jquery masonry if at all possible, but maybe it is the most viable solution.

Comment: if you don't want to reinvent the wheel then it has pretty much everything there